# How can I test accessbility using Lighthouse on a single page application

Tags: accessibility, single-page-application, lighthouse

A colleague showed me Lighthouse on the Chrome browser. I have a single page application (SPA), and I'm able to run it against the base URL of my application.

However, all subsequent screens are rendered by client-side JavaScript without a change to the URL in the browser.

How can I test the rest of my site?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to switch project to server side rendering, like Angular Universal

update: found this issue https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/5187

Answer (score 0):

If you can't switch your project to server side rendering as Alexey Semerenko said, you can consider using another testing tool like Sitespeed.io which allows you to define user actions as a script to browse every pages of your application.

After your test you will gather the same kind of metrics.

Comment: A great combo with easy setup using Cypress: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-audit.  This allows you to introduce ad-hoc lighthouse() calls into your Cypress end-to-end tests when your SPA screens are ready.

Answer (score 0):

As of June 14, 2022 (Chrome 103), Lighthouse now has a Timespan mode available as an option below the default Navigation mode. Timespan mode is used to capture metrics on page interactions such as those in a single-page application (SPA).

Google's release announcement https://developer.chrome.com/en/blog/new-in-devtools-103/

Google's demo video: https://youtu.be/LyMts4yfQu8?t=82